# How to force media player to reconnect to the video stream?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using MediaPlayer for live streaming. It's working nice for certain urls, but for some urls it suddenly stops playing video and never reconnect to the stream. Is there any option in Media Player to reconnect the stream and start the playing it again? I tried implementing

```
OnPreparedListener, OnInfoListener, OnErrorListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener
```

Also I tried `mediaPlayer.isPlaying()` but it always returns `true`

Anykind of help will be really appreciated

Comment: Is it entering any callback when it stops?

Comment: @joao2fast4u no, it isn't. not at all if it enters almost I can have solution..atleast  OnBufferingUpdateListener should get invoked but it is not getting called

Comment: Did you try to stream those URLs in a browser, for making sure they are all right?

Comment: You should check it, then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html) helped me, I noted down all the error code from the given link, later I used those error codes inside OnErrorListener